# Every UIViewController with it's own Navigation bar inside uitabbar (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I am begineer to iOS application development.

My Application flow is like that

It starts as naviagtion controller then after detail page i make custom tab bar as window root controller

**now i have 3 tabs** 
each tab with different ui

means having

**tab1 -> table view**

**tab2  -> grid view**

**tab3 -> with multiple tables**

**now  i want each ui controller must have it's own navigation bar
and also it crossponds to associate tab.**

Thank you for your precious opinion in advance.

Comment: please do a search and implement some thing then tell us about the problems you are facing. Show some effort of your self.

Comment: @Zoain i am just askin about the flow not about the code.

the best possible way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the Custom tab bar controller with three navigation controller for 3 tabs.

Then each navigation controller's root view controller should be your corresponding view controller.

For better understanding please review this image.

[image]

**Programmatically from Tabbarcontroller context**

```
UINavigationController *navCont1;
UINavigationController *navCont2;

UITabBarController *yourTabbarcontroller;

yourTabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];




FirstViewController *viewCont1 = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

navCont1= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewCont1];

UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks tag:1];

[viewCont1 setTabBarItem:tab1];



SecondViewController *viewCont2 = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];

navCont2= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewCont2];

UITabBarItem *tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemDownloads tag:2];

[viewCont2 setTabBarItem:tab2];



tab.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCont1,navnavCont2,nil];

self.window.rootViewController = tab;
```

Comment: then add these navigation view controller on tab pressed. am i right?

Comment: please review the image

Comment: Thanks . one more thing i am using xib. Sorry for inconvineance
but i am new to iOS development.

Comment: then just set the viewcontrollers property of tabbarcontroller, with 3 navigation controller. don't forget to set navigation controller's rootviewcontroller while u create.

Comment: i think rootview controller should be tabview controller and then we just add view controller in navigation view controller and return that navigation view controller

Comment: I have updated my answer from the tab bar controller concept.good luck!